# How can I bind a Winform textbox to a class property?

Tags: c#, winforms, 2-way-object-databinding

I have read a number of questions on Stack Overflow and elsewhere that describe tying a textbox to a class but I cannot seem to even get the basics working without receiving an error from VS when compiling.

(1) What I want to accomplish is to display the text of a property from a class.

(2) When the user modifies that text, I want the property to automatically update.

Unfortunately I cannot even get past (1) yet.

The class:

```
class BookProperties : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string _bookTitle;
    public string bookTitle { get { return _bookTitle; } set { SetField(ref _bookTitle, value, "bookTitle"); } }

    #region handle property changes

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The class initializer:

```
BindingList<BookProperties> bookProperty = new BindingList<BookProperties>();
```

The connection to the textbox:

```
    textBox1.DataBindings.Clear();
    textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bookProperty, "bookProperty.bookTitle");
```

I have also tried this:

```
    textBox1.DataBindings.Clear();
    textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bookProperty, "bookProperty[0].bookTitle");
```

Visual Studio throws the following error:

> Child list for field bookProperty cannot be created.

**START EDIT:** Trying this code, I remove the additional element from the third parameter as a few have suggested.

```
bookProperty.Add(new BookProperties(){bookTitle="C#"});
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bookProperty[0], "bookTitle");
```

Now, I receive this error. I had received it before and searched for a resolution but think it might be too generic for me to figure out what exactly I am doing wrong.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: This causes two bindings in the collection to
>   bind to the same property.

**END EDIT**

I am starting to think there is something fundamentally wrong with my approach since I have seen similar code that people say works so I am hopeful someone can tell me what I am doing wrong. Please note this is a Windows Form issue, not XAML. Thanks.

**FIXED**
Sorry about the last edit. It turns out I had previously attempted to manually link the textbox to a data source using the VS designer. After I removed that data source, everything worked. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Remove name of the instance from third parameter

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
bookProperty.Add(new BookProperties(){bookTitle="C#"});
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bookProperty[0], "bookTitle");
```

Second argument is source that should be shown, third parameter is source class property. Also make sure there is items in bookProperty list.

Hope helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried the code and I am now receiving this error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: This causes two bindings in the collection to bind to the same property.

Comment: Resolved the problem I listed above. Turns out I had previously added a data source to the textbox. Once I removed that from the VS designer, everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're capturing the changes:

```
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bookProperty[0], "bookTitle", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```